# using 'sed' to replace the value in the 1st occurrence of an open/close XML tag with a value that is sum of values from the similar remaining tags

Tags: xml, regex, sed

Say my xml looks like the one below. Expectation is that the 1st occurrence of count    within header should have a value that equals the sum of values of all the count    elements that are present within records. Once the sum is calculated and replaced in     the 1st count tag, all the count tags within records should be deleted along with their values. Row occurrences could vary but header only appears once.

```
<root>
    <!-- Header section, occurs only once per document-->
    <header>
        <count>0</count>
    </header>
    <!-- Records section, could occur more than once-->
    <records>
        <!-- Individual records with id and count-->
        <Row>
            <id>1</id> 
            <count>10</count>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <id>2</id>
            <count>20</count>
        </Row>
    </records>
</root>
```

Comment: You neither want to do this with regular expressions in general nor with sed in particular. Use a proper tool, one that actually supports XML. That being said, this site is not a dumping ground for programming assignments. Do your own work, ask for help when you have some work to show.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk`, not sure if its possible to do with `sed`
This reads the `file` twice. First time counts up the counter from the `records`,
then the second time, update the counter in the header.

```
awk -F"<|>" 'FNR==NR {if (/<records>/) f=1; if (f && /<count>/) s+=$3;next} /<header>/ {g=1} g && /<count>/ {sub(/>[0-9]*</,">"s"<");g=0} /<Row>/ {c=1} !(/<count>/ && c)' file{,}         <root>
    <!-- Header section, occurs only once per document-->
    <header>
        <count>30</count>
    </header>
    <!-- Records section, could occur more than once-->
    <records>
        <!-- Individual records with id and count-->
        <Row>
            <id>1</id>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <id>2</id>
        </Row>
    </records>
</root>
```

`file{,}` is the same as `file file`. To save you from typing the file name twice.

---

Some more readable:

```
awk -F"<|>" '
FNR==NR {
    if (/<records>/)
        f=1
    if (f && /<count>/) 
        s+=$3
    next} 
/<header>/ {g=1}
g && /<count>/ {
    sub(/>[0-9]*</,">"s"<")
    g=0} 
/<Row>/ {c=1} 
!(/<count>/ && c)
' file{,}
```

Comment: He wants the count tags deleted as well except header

Comment: @Jidder Updated post.  And why did he not comment this himself??? Does not read the post we make?

Comment: My system had crashed and my account locked. Am just getting my system back.

Comment: Had tried xslt before posting my question for a production problem here but we ran into memory issues because of the file size which was 1.5 GB. So we used jaxb to get output and then explore if we could use sed or awk to get sum of counts. Had tried the following and that gave the count but was not sure about to go about replacing the tags that we don't need sed -n "/\<records\>/,/\/records>/p" test.xml | grep count |  sed -e "s/<[^>]*>//g" -e "s/ //g" | awk '{ sum+=$1; } END { 

print sum }'

Comment: Thanks Jotne . Your solution has given me enough pointers. Thanks for all your help.